# avoiding for loop in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame similar to this:

```
ID | value | period
a  |  100  |   1   
a  |  100  |   1   
b  |  100  |   1   
a  |  100  |   2   
b  |  100  |   2   
a  |  100  |   3
```

For each period `(1, 2, 3)` I want to filter the data to where period is less than or equal to that number, then sum the value column for each ID.

So for example, period 1 would give `(a:200, b:100)`, period 2 would give `(a:300, b:200)` and period 3 would give `(a:400, b:200)`.

At the moment I'm doing this in a loop:

```
vals = [('a', 100, 1),
        ('a', 100, 1),
        ('b', 100, 1),
        ('a', 100, 2),
        ('b', 100, 2),
        ('a', 100, 3)]
cols = ['ID', 'value', 'period']
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)

for p in (1, 2, 3):
    df_filter = df[df['period'] <= p]
    results = df_filter.groupBy('ID').agg({'value':'sum'})
```

I then convert the "results" to pandas and append them into one DataFrame.

Is there a better way of doing this without having to use a loop? (in practice I have hundreds of periods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combined solution using `pyspark` and `pandas`; Since you said *hundreds of period*, this could be a viable solution; Basically use pyspark to aggregate the data frame first and then convert it to local pandas data frame for further processing:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

local_df = df.groupBy('period').pivot('ID').agg(f.sum('value')).toPandas()

local_df.sort_values('period').fillna(0).set_index('period').cumsum().reset_index()
#   period      a      b
#0       1  200.0  100.0
#1       2  300.0  200.0
#2       3  400.0  200.0
```